# How to make images work in Gatsby with map function

Tags: javascript, image, plugins, graphql, graph-query

I am trying to render an artist image, name, city, and current team. I have tried numerous ways to make this work, but for some reason I just can't seem to get it. They query I used was tested in GraphiQL browser. I would greatly appreciate some insight into Gatsby's use of images. I have read the docs numerous times, and each time I feel I get closer, but I am still stuck. So, any help anyone is willing to give would be greatly appreciated.
This is the component I am trying to render the images in:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

import { useStyles } from './styles'

const ArtistsPage = ({ data }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const imageData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allFile(filter: { extension: { eq: "jpg" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                originalName
              }
              gatsbyImageData
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <section>
      <article className={classes.artistsBackground}>
        <div className={classes.heroLayoutContainer}>
          <h3 className={classes.title}>MEET THE ARTISTS</h3>

          <StaticImage
            className={classes.heroImage}
            src='../../images/artists/hero-images/hero-image-artists.jpg'
            alt='hero-image-artists'
            placeholder='blurred'
          />
        </div>
      </article>

      <article className={classes.artistsContainer}>
        <div className={classes.flexContainer}>
          {data.allArtistsJson.edges
            .map(({ node }, idx) => {
              return (
                <div className={classes.flexItem} key={idx}>
                  <div>
                    {imageData.allFile.edges.map((id) => {
                      const image = getImage(imageData)
                      return (
                        <GatsbyImage
                          image={image}
                          key={id}
                          alt='artist-image'
                        />
                      )
                    })}
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardName}>
                    {`${node.firstName} ${node.lastName}`.toUpperCase()}
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{node.city}</div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardText}>
                    {node.currentTeam}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}

ArtistsPage.propTypes = {
  firstName: PropTypes.string,
  lastName: PropTypes.string,
  currentTeam: PropTypes.string,
  headshots: PropTypes.string,
  dropdown: PropTypes.string,
  data: PropTypes.array,
}

export default ArtistsPage
```

This is my config file:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Platform Showcase',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud',
    // {
    //   resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics",
    //   options: {
    //     trackingId: "",
    //   },
    // },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        icon: 'src/images/icon.png',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: './src/images/',
      },
      __key: 'images',
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `headshots`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/artists/headshots`,
      },
      __key: 'headshots',
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'pages',
        path: './src/pages/',
      },
      __key: 'pages',
    },
    `gatsby-theme-material-ui`,
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
      options: {
        src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        components: path.join(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        containers: path.join(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
        helpers: path.join(__dirname, 'src/helpers'),
        images: path.join(__dirname, 'src/images'),
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

And my actual artist page component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import ArtistsContainer from 'containers/ArtistsContainer'

const Artists = ({ data }) => {
  return <ArtistsContainer data={data} />
}
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allArtistsJson {
      edges {
        node {
          firstName
          lastName
          currentTeam
          city
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`

Artists.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array,
}
export default Artists
```

And all the images I am trying to use are located in:
images/artists/headshots/

Thank you in advance for any help, I have gone in numerous circles and can't seem to get anywhere productive.

Comment: missing `node` [and accessing node props - console.log them to check structure] as in `.map()` a few lines earlier

Comment: @xadm When I add node to {imageData.alllFile.edges.node.map()
I get a cannot read property of undefined error. I am so confused. I have been working on this one task for two weeks and can't seem to get anything to populate.

Comment: it looks like you don't **understand** your(?) code from earlier lines

Comment: how can you use `edges.map()`  properly in one place and wrongly a few lines later?! this is the same schema ... follow some tutorials [about edges/node pagination in react] to understanding **all** code level?

Comment: @xadm my understanding is that they are not the same schema as one comes from allArtistsJson and the other comes from allFile. So they would not be queried the same way.

Comment: false ... compare `console.log(data, imageData);` structures, **fetching/querying doesn't matter**, ... in react FC (in gatsby) before `return` you have **the same data structures** (of course with different prop/name above `edges` - the one and only difference), standard [the most common in graphql] edges/node ('relay style') pagination